# MongoDB connection error on AWS ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have trying to connect to my mongo server on ec2 instance from my app hosted on elastic beanstalk.

It worked when authorization was NOT enabled. I could connect through both local IP and public IP.

Then I added users to the DB and enabled authorization in server. I could connect to the server using mongodb://user:password@ec2IP/27017 from any commandline interface.

Using the same mongo URI from the elasticbeanstalk app I cannot connect to the mongodb server. This is the error I am getting -

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [<user-name-mongo-server>:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <user-name-mongo-server> <user-name-mongo-server>:27017
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check your mongodb server is running?

Comment: yes, as I said, I can connect it remotely using the same mongod:// URI from any CLI

Comment: Then first try to connect on the 'Robo 3T' and the run your app again.

Comment: Robo 3T connection is working fine also.

Comment: Then, in your app, check your authorization information

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,

I had passwords that included either a

> %

or a

> ?

which was the problem for mongoose connection.

so my mongo URI looked like this -

```
mongodb://<user>:<password-including-%-or-?>@IP:port/dbname
```